# .htaccess regex for HTTP_HOST followed by a specific folder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to edit my .htaccess file to do the following:
1) Determine if the HTTP_HOST is not my own domain, example.com
2) Determine if it is otherdomain.com/admin/_anything_here_

/admin/ is the specific folder I am looking for, then I don't care what comes after it (but I do need to keep it there). So basically anything that has /admin/ as the first folder and isn't example.com should rewrite to otherdomain.com/admin/_anything_still_here_

It's my understanding that using (.*)$ will "store" the _anything_here_ part and allow me to use it with $1.

I have this so far but it isn't working fully:

```
RewriteCond ^%{HTTP_HOST}+(/admin.*)$ !^([^.]+\.)*example\.com+(/admin.*)
RewriteRule (.*)$ rewrite/to/here$1/ [L]
```

Comment: I do not understand what `/admin...` be rewritten to. Give an example.
for `otherdomain.com/admin/_anything_here_` => `otherdomain.com/admin/_anything_still_here_`

Comment: Sorry, that's a tad unclear. Basically, otherdomain.com/admin/_anything_here_ should rewrite to rewrite/to/here$1/ where $1 is whatever was _anything_here_. The reasn I had _anything_still_here_ was just to make it obvious that I don't want to chop of the stuff that comes after /admin/. Does that help?

Comment: Not much. lets say the URL was this: `otherdomain.com/admin/site/old`. What should this be rewritten to?

Comment: It would rewrite to otherdomain.com/rewrite/to/here/admin/site/old

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site.

You need to replace `somefolder` with the actual folder you want to rewrite to

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#if its not example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example\.com$ [NC] 
#if its admin folder, rewrite it to somefolder
RewriteRule ^(admin/.*)$  somefolder/$1[L,NC]
```

The above assumes that `otherdomain.com` and `example.com` are on the same server with the same root folder.

Comment: The RewriteRule part alone is causing it to work it seems. Not sure if that's entirely the right way to do it (i.e. if it'll cause problems elsewhere), though. I'll try to work with that a little bit.

Comment: @joshholat The `RewriteCond` is only needed if you are hosting multiple sites that have the same root directory